# inMemoryDataService unable to parse URL

Tags: javascript, angular

I have set up an mock inMemoryDataService class as suggested by Angular 2 tutorial. But as soon I start the page I get an error, that the URL cannot be parsed.

Error:

```
EXCEPTION: unable to parse url 'commission.json'; 
original error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

*I even tried adding `/` before the URL, but it didn't help.*

mock.ts

```
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        let commission = {
            prop: 'string',
            ...
        }
        return {
            'commission.json': commission
        }
    }
}
```

some.service.ts

```
export class LogoService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    private connect(): Promise<void> {
        return this.http.get('commission.json').toPromise().then(...)
    }
}
```

I know that the I don't really return a promise, but it is a private function, and it is yet handeled otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your files to the following:

```
//mock.ts

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
createDb() {
    let commission = {
        prop: 'string',
        ...
    }
    return { commission };
}
}

//some.service.ts
export class LogoService {

constructor(private http: Http) {}

private connect(): Promise<void> {
    return this.http.get('api/commission').toPromise().then(...)
}
}
```